# Doctrine2 findOneBy argument equivalent to BETWEEN in SQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to be able to use the following WHERE clause in Doctrine:

`WHERE AL.UserID = 41 AND (TheDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)  AND CURDATE())`

and what I'm currently doing is:

`$results = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyTable')->findOneBy(array('userId' => $userId));`

However, I haven't been able to filter results by the last 2 weeks without writing SQL or DQL.

Is there any way I can achieve this through Doctrine's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). Assuming you are using MySQL `BETWEEN`, something like:

```
<?php

// $em instanceof EntityManager
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$now = new DateTime();
$qb->select('c')
   ->from('MyClass', 'c')
   ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
       $qb->expr()->eq('c.UserID', '?1'),
       $qb->expr()->gte('c.TheDate', '?2'),
       $qb->expr()->lte('c.TheDate', '?3')
   ))
   ->setParameter(1, 41)
   ->setParameter(2, $now.sub(new DateInterval('P2W')))
   ->setParameter(3, $now);
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$c = $query->getSingleResult();
```

This is cleaner code and should work across the different database platforms supported by Doctrine2 ORM.